# Loading .txt content in HTML file? If not, then where?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, xml

Very new to code. Searching for 2 days has yielded no results and I've gone nearly mad.

I have this [CSS designed bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUDPw.png) that I use in my live streaming overlays. I'm trying to populate text from a local .txt, xml, or json file onto the bar. I just cant figure out how to call this text and then style it.

Why? I'd like to eventually write a python script/GUI that can read / write to the .txt file (if its json or xml, ill try to figure it out). Baby steps.

So far, everything is div boxes and a video that is clipped to create the black bar (its looped to look animated).

Using

> embed src="txtfile.txt"

loads up the file, but I cant style it T_T. I would really appreciate the help!

Main question. With this file that I am opening locally - how can I (on the backend) select a text file to be read, and then style that text?

I really appreciate the help or even a nudge in the right direction. I am so lost.

Comment: You can retrieve the file contents using *ajax* then parse it's contents to insert into elements within the page and style those elements. Lots of tutorials around on how to use ajax with text, json, xml etc

Comment: Could you please provide some codes, just so we can understand clearly what you really want?

Comment: @AdnaneAr honestly there isnt much code yet. I've included the one and only snippet that allowed me to pull text from a file - but didnt allow me to style it. Its in the initial post.

Comment: @charlietfl I'll take a look into ajax. I'm new to this whole thing so I'm looking for the least complex way to implement this. The whole thing is loaded into OBS as a browser source. Then encoded and sent to my stream. All code stays completely offline.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a server language. I recommend using PHP as you are new to code. First you will need to set up a PHP supported development server for developing. You can search how to do this yourself as its out of the scope of your question (WAMP/MAMP/XAMPP).

If you are using PHP as your server language. presuming txtfile.txt is located in the same directory as your CSS designed bar, you can do the following:

```
<?php

// specify txt file path
include 'txtfile.txt'; 

// store txt file contents as string
$my_string = file_get_contents('txtfile.txt');

?>
```

Then wherever you want the string to appear, just echo the variable. Here's an example:

```
<span class="myCustomClass"><?php echo $my_string; ?></span>
```

You can then style whatever class you gave it in CSS.

Oh, and remember to change the file extension to .php

- You can also use other server languages to achieve this.

Alternatively, you could embed the txt file in an iframe, and place the iframe inside the element you want:

```
<iframe src='txtfile.txt' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

...and there are other ways, too! Look into using jQuery and AJAX as it may be easier to do without the hassle of using PHP.  You can just load the text file via an AJAX call, insert it inside the document and then you can style the content with CSS.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to write this out.

I will take a look and give it a shot. 

Just to clarify, do I have to setup a php supported development server if everything is going to stay local?

Comment: If you are going to use PHP, you will need to have PHP installed on your computer. Alternatively, you could just embed the txt file in an iframe and place the iframe within whatever element you want it in. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I appreciate it! You're probably right and iframe will work, and I just dont understand how iframes function. 

if I can give it a class / id, and style the text that is pulled in, I am completely satisfied. 

I did see that with AJAX, I can use fetch() in JS and have the text update without refreshing the page. I'm looking into how to accomplish that.